# Error: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array

Tags: php, arrays, string, arguments

Error:

> implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given

Here is my code and have been receiving same errors. What can I do?

```
        $userLogin->longitude = @implode(',',$info['long']);


        $userLogin->longitude = @implode('',$info['long']);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged this with [python]?

Comment: just looking for answers

Comment: If it's not a question about python, don't tag it as [python].

Comment: See [offical documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: *$info['long']* is an array branch or is it a string?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the bits about writing a meaningful title, and doing some prior research. That will help your question to be better received next time

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the php manual;
implode(string $separator, array $array): string

Implode takes 2 arguments:

1. A string to combine the parts of an array with
2. An array

You are currently passing 2 strings due to specifying the array index.

What you want to do is this:

```
$userLogin->longitude = @implode(',',$info[]);
```

Or if you don't want the whole array, make a new array with the data you want to concat from $info[].

Comment: the *$info[]* notation can be used only for assignements

Comment: Just $info not $info[]